# AJAX progress bar dispaying loading progress percentage for page load

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-ajax, progress-bar

How do you use a progressbar to show the loading percentage for a page? ...(similar to how they show in flash)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Impossible(on IE8 & FF3 & Opera without plugin or extension). If you want real loading percentage include HTML + Javascript + Stylesheet + Image. you can only detect how many file loaded to page(only Image & javascript can be detected by this technique).

Answer (score 5):

I would say that if you need a progressbar for a page, that page might need some rethinking.

Personally I don't like pages that have progress bars (Like the one in the ASUS Download Area). They are just annoying. My browser already have a progressbar. And I would like my bandwidth to be used to download the page and not graphics that would just tell me that I am still waiting for the page.

When it comes to AJAX requests ON a page though, I would just use a spinner thing of some sort. To tell the user that something is going on and that the page is not dead. And again, if the background request takes so long that you would need a progressbar, I would again say that the background request should maybe be rethought.

Comment: I think so. double progress bar for what? you just need only loading indicator for AJAX request.

Comment: huh? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I mean double progress bar(both in web browser and in web page) is unnecessary. Only loading indicator is required when webpage is using ajax for request something.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand the meaning of your comment... "Progressbar both in browser and page is unnecessary", isn't that exactly what I said? Same with the "I am doing something"-indicator for ajax requests. Did you agree/disagree, come with some extra information that I am not picking up? or? (I don't mean to be picky or anything, I just like to know what people are saying when they are commenting my answers, since there could be room for improvement on my part)

Comment: I believe is agreeing with you in all. I think is a bad thing you can't display the real progress of let's say... an image. You may be seeing that something is happening but you don't know for how long, which is frustrating. Maybe you have a photo gallery and a slow connection, if something happens and the connection breaks you think is still working because of the spinner, but if you could have a progress bar you know that is not working.

Answer (score 2):

oh that so easy, you copy down my code and paste on your website, however is not very cool, but still can use.

CODE : `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript' SRC='http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/progress.js' TYPE='text/javascript'>
</SCRIPT>`

> REMEMBER THIS CODE IS PASTE BETWEEN  "/Head" and "BODY"
>
> ```
>   [1]: http://dw6-vista-tdx.blogspot.com
> ```

Comment: If you want to use this, I'd recommend you download the .js file and put it on your own server. Linking to a JavaScript file on a website that you don't have some reason to trust completely is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, check out the upload progress dialog at [s3fm](http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3fm/index.html), a free online Amazon s3 file manager.

Comment: How could be an upload progress helpful with page loading progress?