# Get the percentage of the page load using javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, time, load, progress

I'm writing an iphone application and need to show a progress bar that shows the loading progress of a web page. I want to insert a JS function to this page and once I call it, it will give me the load progress (how much bytes have been loaded and the total size). Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: If your page needs a progress bar, that is a sign that is too big. Furthermore, major browsers have an integrated progress bar, that is much more efficient than any JS hack.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You can emulate it by breaking up your page to small pieces and load it one by one with ajax requests but I don't think it is worth the trouble.

Another idea is to put little pieces of script like

```
<script>percentage += 10; updateProgressBar();</script>
```

through your page. That script will be executed the second browser loads (or parses) it so you will be able to estimate the progress.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible using Javascript, and unless the page is VERY big, I don't see why you'd need this.  If you have lots of images on the page, this may be possible to tell how many of them are fully loaded.

Edit: I found [this](http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/progress.htm), that looks like want you want to do.

Edit 2 : And [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796792/ajax-progress-bar-dispaying-loading-progress-percentage-for-page-load).

Comment: Technically I'm pretty sure it would be possible (even if complicated).. If you send a <script> in the head it will be executed right away; and you can navigate the DOM, and server-side you know how the full DOM looks like, so in theory it's possible

Comment: I think that checking the number of loaded images is what I need. I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

How do you know what percentage of the HTML is loaded by Safari? Javascript from what I know of 1.7 can never be aware of that. If it did you would have far more sophisticated loaders for Gmail and the wealth of Google apps. You can do very crude estimations by injecting scripts and elements into the DOM programatically but it's a lot of effort for not much gain.

The best you can hope for is an animated GIF that runs for how long you'd estimate the page to load in a worst case scenario. Or the easier solution is to just use a [throbber, hour glass or barber's pole](http://www.ajaxload.info/).

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" type="javascript">
var percent=0;

function curpercent(){
    //TODO : show percent : $("#lblpercent").html(percent + "%");
    if (percent <=100) {
        curpercent();
    }

}

curpercent(); //call curpercent function when page download this line, coz, browser always download your page line by line.

</script>

text body 1
<script type="text/javascript" type="javascript">
percent=10;
</script>

text body 2
<script type="text/javascript" type="javascript">
percent=20;
</script>

...

text body 10
<script type="text/javascript" type="javascript">
percent=100;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try to explain your answer and don't just make questioner guess what you implied in your reply.