# Finding percentage of webpage loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am trying to implement a loading bar for my website. It is similar to the Gmail loading bar that shows up when we login.

I am trying to show the progress by moving a picture from left to right by altering its css width property. I want to move the picture as the main page is getting loaded but i have no idea how to find how much of the main page has been loaded.

How do i find how much of a webpage has been loaded or how much of it is still left?

Should i use client-side scripts or server-side scripts for this?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958624/get-the-percentage-of-the-page-load-using-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Its not possible @user2878249